# Twilio GET request to Google Apps Script returning HTTP error 413 - response was too large

Tags: google-apps-script, twilio, whatsapp

I am developing an application on Twilio, where the user can send some information to a ChatBot via WhatsApp, and then an application running on a Google Apps Script standalone script generates and returns a PDF file with the user's information. The first GET request to GAS returns the export link from Google Drive, which I then use as "MediaURL" link in the second request, which should return the file itself, but then I get the HTTP error 413 - response was too large. The files returned have around 60 kB (way below the maximum size of 5 MB on Twilio), and when tested on other tools, such as HTTPie or Postman, the GAS API works like a charm. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're responding via WhatsApp, so may not apply...however, you've probably seen this already, but looks like some major carriers do *not* support .PDF docs sent from long-code numbers.

> Long code MMS support for PDF files
> The AT&T mobile network in the United States, as well as Fido, Rogers, and Telus in Canada do not support PDF attachments on MMS messages sent via long codes (standard 10-digit local numbers) toward subscribers on their networks.
> For users on these mobile networks, a PDF file attachment on an MMS message will not reach the device. The user will receive the Body text of your message (if one was included), with the following text appended: "One or more of the message components have been deleted by MMS Adaptation. Either the message was too large or the components were unsuitable for your handset."

[Carrier Support for PDF files](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056727314-Carrier-support-for-PDF-files-sent-using-Twilio-MMS#:%7E:text=Please%20note%20that%20PDF%20files,size%20limit%20for%20media%20files.)

Comment: Thank you for looking up, but yes, I am using WhatsApp instead of MMS. I have already tried the same request using a static pdf file and it works, so it doesn't seem to be a carrier limitation.